# Difference between forms of Culture Fair Intelligence Test (CFIT) scale 3

Tags: intelligence, test

I would really like to know what are the differences between the form A and form B of Cattell's Culture Fair Intelligence Test scale 3?

To my knowledge (reading the "methods" section in the scientific literature) they seem to have the same number of problems and subsets. Do they differ in the time allowed to solve them?

Sometimes the researchers use both forms together (A+B) sometimes they only use one. Why? Less administration time?

Or are they alternative versions which exist to be able to test the subjects twice?
Are there reasons to prefer one over the other (MENSA only uses form A)?

Comment: Welcome to cogsci.SE!  Citations or sources for the intelligence scale itself and methods sections where it's used would help your readers answer exactly the question you're asking.